# jQuery Click Function: Show Div Based on Previous Radio Button Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button, show

I have been searching for an answer all day but can't seem to find anything that would help my specific problem so here goes.

In a question form, I want to show hidden divs based on radio button selections, using the jQuery click() function. But after a second click() event is triggered, the div that was shown in the previous selection is forgotten, and returned to hidden status.

Here is an example code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr("value")=="answer1"){
                jQuery(".hide").hide();
                jQuery(".answer1").show();
                jQuery(".answer1and2").show();
            }                                                                                    
            if(jQuery(this).attr("value")=="answer2"){
                jQuery(".hide").hide();
                jQuery(".answer2").show();
                jQuery(".answer1and2").show();
            }
            if(jQuery(this).attr("value")=="answer3"){
                jQuery(".hide").hide();
                jQuery(".answer1and2").show();
                jQuery(".answer3").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Question 1</h1>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer1">
Answer 1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer2">
Answer 2
    
<div class="answer1 hide">
<p>Answer 1 is Apple</p>
</div>

<div class="answer2 hide">
<p>Answer 2 is Mango</p>
</div>
 
<div class="answer1and2 hide">
<h1>Question 2</h1>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer3">
Any answer
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer3">
Any answer
</div>

<div class="answer3 hide">
<p>Did you choose Apple or Mango?</p>
</div>
```

How can I retain just one of the answers that was shown after the first selection?

[JSFiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/)

Comment: jQuery(".hide").hide(); <= This row hides all divs, that have "hide" as a class. Why do you hide them? aren't they already hidden? Do you have .hide class defined in your css or smth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want shown divs to be hidden again, then just remove "hide" class from items you get "shown"

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/0vc9ep17/1/)**

And here is one example row of how to do that:

```
         jQuery(".answer1").show().removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: This would be the simplest / quickest fix to your problem. +1 for simplicity.

Comment: Great answer and ".removeClass('hide')" turned out very useful as well! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove every

```
jQuery(".hide").hide();
```

(now with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/3/))